# Retrieve print function code for an S4 class/object

Tags: r, function, class, printing, r-s4

I am working with an S4 object (PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject). When I type the name of an instance of this class into the console and hit enter, I get something like the following:

```
Global PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: ATCGATCGATCGATCG
subject: -TCGATCG-TCGATC-
score: -16.23717
```

The actual class is much larger than just this, so I assume some print function for the class is being called. I really want to see the code used in this print function, but I cannot figure out how to pull it up. Could someone please offer some insights into this?

Thank you

Edit based on JDL's answer:
I was able to use selectMethod (I guess this class inherits its "print" function). However, the result is just:

```
> selectMethod("print",signature(x="BioStrings"))
Method Definition (Class "derivedDefaultMethod"):

function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0x5572111b6d58>
<environment: namespace:base>

Signatures:
        x           
target  "BioStrings"
defined "ANY"
```

Which is still not very informative and definitely not the full code for the function. Does anyone know how I can take this further?

Comment: Based on the edit, it looks like `BioStrings` is an S3 class, not an S4 one. There are two ways you might find what you want: (1) try converting `print` to a formal S4 generic using `setGeneric("print")` and register the S3 class as S4 using `setOldClass("BioStrings")`, or (2) look for a function called `print.BioStrings`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the code associated with a method, the function to use is `getMethod`. If you know the class you are interested in then the call is of the form below

`getMethod("print",signature(x="numeric"))`

which in your specific case is

`getMethod("print",signature(x="PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject"))`.

If you have an object `obj` and want to see what code will be applied to it when you call `print`, then a slight modification allows this:

`getMethod("print",signature(x=class(obj)))`

This also works for any generic function, you can substitute `"plot"` etc. in place of `"print"`.

Note that this only works for methods defined for the exact class you specified. If there isn't such a method (i.e. one based on inheritance was used instead), then replace `getMethod` with `selectMethod`.

For further information, consult the help page at `?getMethod` which documents these and some similar functions.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a bit, but I think there is still more code I am not seeing. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through their github is usually useful :)

They don't use 'print' but 'show'.

If you look at the source code for the [class PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject](https://github.com/Bioconductor/Biostrings/blob/4f9031a1bc0e102148060cd39aa441d812d75ce7/R/PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject-class.R) you can see a show method, but it's only for the class PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubjectSummary.

But in the last method for 'PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject' you see it creates a 'newPairwiseAlignments' and if you look a the source code for the [class PairwiseAlignments](https://github.com/Bioconductor/Biostrings/blob/4f9031a1bc0e102148060cd39aa441d812d75ce7/R/PairwiseAlignments-class.R) you'll find the "show" method starting at line 398.

```r
### - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
### The "show" method
###
### TODO: Maybe make the "show" method format the alignment in a SGD fashion
### i.e. split in 60-letter blocks and use the "|" character to highlight
### exact matches.
###

.show_PairwiseAlignments <- function(x)
{
    x_len <- length(x)
    if (x_len == 0L)
        cat("Empty ")
    cat(switch(type(x), "global"="Global", "overlap"="Overlap",
               "local"="Local", "global-local" = "Global-Local",
               "local-global"="Local-Global"),
        " ", class(x), sep="")
    if (x_len == 0L) {
        cat("\n")
        return()
    }
    cat(" (1 of ", x_len, ")\n", sep="")
    x1 <- x[1L]

    x_type <- type(x)
    global.pattern <- x_type %in% c("global", "global-local")
    global.subject <- x_type %in% c("global", "local-global")
    p1start <- if (global.pattern)
                   ""
               else
                   paste0("[", start(x1@pattern@range), "]")
    s1start <- if (global.subject)
                   ""
               else
                   paste0("[", start(x1@subject@range), "]")
    width <- max(nchar(p1start), nchar(s1start))
    if (width != 0L) {
        width <- width + 1L
        p1start <- format(p1start, justify="right", width=width)
        s1start <- format(s1start, justify="right", width=width)
    }

    width <- getOption("width") - 9L - width
    pattern1 <- toSeqSnippet(alignedPattern(x1)[[1L]], width)
    subject1 <- toSeqSnippet(alignedSubject(x1)[[1L]], width)
    cat("pattern:", p1start, " ", add_colors(pattern1), "\n", sep="")
    cat("subject:", s1start, " ", add_colors(subject1), "\n", sep="")
    cat("score:", score(x1), "\n")
}

setMethod("show", "PairwiseAlignments",
    function(object) .show_PairwiseAlignments(object)
)
```